# Symfony images folder

Tags: php, image, symfony, upload, vendor

I recently set up the upload module on my website. However, I feel like it is too messy to put every pictures in one directory. So I have decided to create one folder per user using symfony. Once a user gets registered, a copy and paste an existing folder and then work with the name (user id) attribute to distinguish the different folders.

So i added an attribute called name

```
private $name;

public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __dir__ . '/../../../../web/uploads/'. $this->getName();
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->path;
}

public function getWebPath($name) {

    return 'uploads/' . $name->getId() . '/' . $this->path;
}

public function getAssetPath()
{
    return 'uploads/' . $this->getName() . '/' . $this->path;
}
```

The uploads works fine, in the controller, I do something like:

```
 $imageProfile->getImage()->setName($user->getId());
```

It uploads the pictures in the good directory.

To display the picture, I do the following:

```
<img  class="img-responsive"src="{{ asset(player.base.getWebPath(user)) }}" />
```

Everything works smoothly with this and I can see the picture and it is in the good folder.

Problem:

I am getting this error when I wanna display the picture as well as the form to edit the picture.

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for COC\COCBundle\Entity\Image::getWebPath(), called in C:\wamp\www\symfony_coc\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php on line 310 and defined

I guess it comes with the parameter "name" I added to the getWebPath() method but I don't get why this relates to a vendor error. (I tried to delete and generate it again, same problem)

Your help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you get when you dump() user?

Comment: Foa, thanks for your answer. I get this which is expected:

private 'path' (COC\COCBundle\Entity\Image) => string 'b6a762e8beb8eb314495dc51b8dca523f644e73f.jpeg' (length=45) public 'file' => null private 'iduser' (COC\COCBundle\Entity\Image) => int 1

(File is null because i havent submitted anything in the page, I just would like to display my picture ... )

Answer (score 0):

Your error, it is normal that it is related to vendor since symfony is in vendor too and PropertyAccessor is one of its component which handles accessing properties of entity and trying to access your webpath but the name parameter is missing so it generate this error.

Maybe you should check if you call getWebPath somewhere else in the project then add your parameter to it.

If this line is the only one that uses getWebPath then maybe its your cache and that your cache still have the version of :  `{{ asset(player.base.getWebPath()) }}` without parameter, if thats the case then try to clear your cache in your console folder of your project :

`php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-warmup --no-debug`

or --env=prod if using prod(app.php).

If that doesn't work try it the hard way with :

`sudo rm -R  app/cache/dev/twig/` or  `app/cache/prod/twig/`